# phone login in flutter with firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I integrated phone login in my app but whenever I log in I have to wait for the OTP. how do I check in the Starting if the user is registered/logged-in? if yes then redirect it to the home page directly. or else to the phone login page.

i tried this code below but it is showing the error of an undefined class 'FirebaseUser'.

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser user;


  void getCurrentUser() async{
    FirebaseUser _user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      user = _user;
    });
  }
```

can anyone help it's a bit confusing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseUser there is no such a class replace it with User

```
User _user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
```